# Octopus Deploy octo-pack is including a folder

Tags: octopus-deploy

I am using Octopus Deploy to deploy an angular application to Azure. To do this, I have used `grunt-octo`, which packages the deployment into a nuget package and sends it to Octopus Deploy.

The packing part of this process is taking the files from the dist folder. Here is the `octo-pack` part of the Grunt script:

```
'octo-pack': {
  prod: {
    options: {
      dst: './bin'
    },
    src: ['dist/**/*']
  }
}
```

However, this includes the `dist` folder in the deployment, so my files are inside a dist folder in Azure.

I have not been able to find a way to just get the files within the folder.

Octopus Deploy lets you run a Powershell script as part of the process, but I don't think that is a good solution.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer in the Octopus forums:
http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/problems/47569-grunt-octopack

The key part of the article is this:

> The grunt-octo modules currently does not support the dynamic file list feature provided by grunt

This stops the CDW (Current Working Directory) part from working correctly.

I have submitted this Pull Request to add some additional parameters to fix this issue:
https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/grunt-octo/pull/2

This adds 2 new parameters to the options, where you can specify if you want the parent folder to be removed and to specify the name of the folder to remove:

```
options: {
  dst: './bin',
  removeParent: true,
  parentDir: 'dist'
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Since I submitted the Pull Request, the package has been updated to honor the working directory. This will now work using the following code:

```
'octo-pack': {
  prod: {
    options: {
      dst: './bin'
    },
    src: ['**/*'],
    cwd: 'dist'
  }
},
```